# Skip zero values in barchart -- Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a code that plots a custom bar chart:

```
def bar_chartQ2(sizes, colors, x_labels, c_labels, file_name):
    y, x = sizes.shape
    ind = np.arange(y)*8
    width = 0.7

    plt.figure()
    for i in range(x):
        plt.bar(ind + width*i, sizes[:, i], width, color=colors[i], label=c_labels[i])

c_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'Unknown'] 
x_labels = ['1)', '2)', '3)', '4)', '5)']
sizes = np.array([[2, 8, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                  [2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [2, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 3],
                  [1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 4, 0, 2],
                  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2]])
colors = ['royalblue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'deepskyblue', 'deeppink', 'limegreen', 'firebrick']

bar_chartQ2(sizes, colors, x_labels, c_labels, 'Q2')
    plt.legend(loc=(1.2, 0.2), shadow=True)
    plt.xticks(ind + x/2.0*width, x_labels)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(file_name+'.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

So far, this is the result:

[image]

I think it is kind of unreadable.

I would like to skip bars with size == 0, i.e., preventing empty spaces between bars of the same item.

Comment: Just a note but: what about people that are color blind? In that cse the position can still help them understand the result.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, @WillemVanOnsem. But how it is now, don't you consider hard to identify the clusters? I mean, there were 5 questions with 8 options each. Without the colors, I can't identify which bars correspond to each question. Maybe some pattern instead of color would be better. Or some other approach.

Comment: I recommend that you plot each cluster on it's own axes, and then you label the position of each bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that plots all of your data on separate axes:

```
import numpy 
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn

c_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', 'Unknown'] 
colors = ['royalblue', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'purple', 'deepskyblue', 'deeppink', 'limegreen', 'firebrick']
x_labels = ['1)', '2)', '3)', '4)', '5)']
sizes = numpy.array([
    [2, 8, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [2, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 1, 3],
    [1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 4, 0, 2],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2]
])

fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(ncols=sizes.shape[0], figsize=(10, 5), sharey=True)
for ax, height, title in zip(axes, sizes, x_labels):
    ax.set_title(title)

    left = numpy.arange(len(height)) + 1
    ax.bar(left, height, color=colors)

    ax.set_xticks(left)
    ax.set_xticklabels(c_labels, rotation=45, rotation_mode='anchor', ha='right')
```

[image]

Comment: How do I get the legend to show? I tried `handles, labels = axes[0].get_legend_handles_labels()` followed by 
    `plt.legend(handles, labels)` (outside the loop) but it doesn't appear at all....

Comment: Also, when I save this plot using `plt.tight_layout()` and ` plt.savefig(file_name+'.pdf', format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight')` all text disappear. This is just happening with this `seaborn` package.