# How to plot without including null values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, null

I am trying to create a plot that includes the top 5 wind energy-generating countries during three separate years. Each year should only include 5 countries, and there are 7 countries included in the plot as some lose their status as 'top 5'. However, when a country loses its status, there is an empty space where its bar would be. Essentially, each year should only have 5 countries but they actually have 7 with 2 blanks. How do I remove these blanks? Should I actually plot each dataframe separately and create subplots?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# top 5 wind generation in 2000, 2010, 2020

#read file, remove unwanted columns, remove entity groups
df = pd.read_csv('~/Python/Projects/Jupyter Notebooks/Jupyter Notes and Exercises/Exercises/Energy Exercises/archive/wind-generation.csv')
df = df.drop('Code', axis=1)
df = df[~df['Entity'].isin(['OECD', 'Non-OECD', 'North America', 'South & Central America', 'Europe',
                         'Asia Pacific', 'European Union', 'World', 'Africa', 'Upper-middle-income countries','G20','G7',
                            'European Union (27)','High-income countries','Asia', 
                            'Lower-middle-income countries','Latin America and Caribbean','South America'])]
# filter for select years
df_2000 = df[df['Year'].isin([2000])]
df_2010 = df[df['Year'].isin([2010])]
df_2020 = df[df['Year'].isin([2020])]

# create pivot table
df = df.pivot_table(index='Year', columns='Entity', values='Electricity from wind (TWh)')

# sort dataframes to filter only top 5 from each year
df_2000.sort_values('Electricity from wind (TWh)', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df_2010.sort_values('Electricity from wind (TWh)', ascending=False, inplace=True)
df_2020.sort_values('Electricity from wind (TWh)', ascending=False, inplace=True)

df_2000 = df_2000[0:5]
df_2010 = df_2010[0:5]
df_2020 = df_2020[0:5]

# combine dataframes
df_20_years = pd.concat([df_2000,df_2010,df_2020])

df_20_years = df_20_years.pivot_table(index='Year',
                                      columns='Entity',
                                      values='Electricity from wind (TWh)')

df_20_years.plot(kind='bar',
                 xlabel='Year',
                 ylabel='Wind Generation (TWh)',
                title='Generation of Wind Energy by \nTop 5 Wind Energy-Producing Countries',
                figsize=(8,4),
                rot=0,
                grid=True)

plt.savefig('Wind Energy Top 5.png', facecolor='white')

plt.show()
```

Here are the dataframe and plot that result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: i was unable to find a good solution, i'm sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip zero values in barchart -- Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725409/skip-zero-values-in-barchart-matplotlib)